# Where can I find Honedge with Stance Change?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm trying to catch a Honedge with the Stance Change ability, but for some reason all the ones I've caught so far have No Guard. Is there only a specific place where they'll have that ability, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Honedge](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Honedge) (as well as [Doublade](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Doublade_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)) only have one possible ability, No Guard. Upon being evolved to [Aegislash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aegislash_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) (use a Dusk Stone on a Doublade), No Guard will become [Stance Change](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stance_Change_%28Ability%29). Aegislash is the only (current) Pokemon with the Sance Change ability.

Comment: Oh. I thought I had seen Honedge and Doublade were able to change forms between sheathed and unsheathed in promo art and screenshots.

Comment: @Cobalt If you watch Honedge and Doublade come out of their PokéBalls, you'll see why they have that design ;)